# Why gtk-launch doesn't interpret .desktop file environment variables?

Tags: linux, gtk

I have set up a custom .desktop file for an application with the following command to execute :

`Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb konsole`

When I launch the application, it works well. I have a terminal as root.

But when I try to launch the .desktop file through gtk-launch, it doesn't launch properly and I noticed the env variables DISPLAY=$DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY where not set with their values. (there are user env variables set in ~/.profile)

If i manually set the variables in the .desktop file such as
`Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=:1 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/xauth_XXXX QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb konsole`
it launches properly with gtk-launch.

Is there an explanation to why gtk-launch does not work when environment variables values are not hardcoded within the .desktop file ?
Is there any mean to make it work with DISPLAY=$DISPLAY ?